# Left join in Doctrine Query Language

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, doctrine

I want to apologies if I haven't done enough research in google but to be honest I don't know exactly what to search for. My problem is with Doctrine. I use Symfony framework and I want to write the following raw query in DQL:

```
SELECT c.id AS id,
c.name AS name,
c.active AS active,
count(c2.id) AS depth,
(c.rht - c.lft) as rng
FROM (categories c
LEFT JOIN categories c2 ON ( (c2.lft < c.lft) AND (c2.rht > c.rht) AND c2.active ) )
GROUP by c.id
ORDER by c.lft ASC
```

I can write it like a raw query, but I need it in DQL as I want to use it for a sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice widget. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention this early - 1.2 (as I still stick to Symfony 1.4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible approuch would be:

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->select('c.name AS name,
            c.active AS active,
            count(c2.id) AS depth,
            (c.rht - c.lft) as rng')
  ->from('categories c')
  ->leftJoin('c.Categories c2 ON ( (c2.lft < c.lft) AND (c2.rht > c.rht) AND c2.active')
  ->groupBy('c.id')
  ->orderBy('c.lft ASC');
```

But I think your on the wrong way. Did you check out the tree behavior of doctrine? http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0/nl/hierarchical-data#nested-set:advanced-usage:fetching-a-tree-with-relations

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This isn't the answer of my question - it's much more that I wanted. Thanks for the help!

P.S. I managed to do it but in order to make a join Doctrine requires a relation with local and foreign columns so I've created a dummy relation so I can make a left join and then to override the condition as by default it uses local.foreign_id = foreign.id relation